# Java Oracle Transaction

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, transactions

I want to insert data into a database into different tables. Because of constraints I have to do this in a specific order. That means, first insert into table a, then b, then c , .... and no mixing of the tables.
But I'm writing a program, which get multiple csv files and should import them into the database, but the program can't know what is the right order. So I thought transaction would be the right way, because I heard, that the data consistency must only exists at the end of the transaction. But that doesn't works

My code looks like that:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pw);
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.addBatch("INSERT INTO c ....");
statement.addBatch("INSERT INTO a ....");
statement.addBatch("INSERT INTO b ....");
statement.addBatch("INSERT INTO a ....");
// ...
statement.executeBatch();
statement.close();
connection.commit();
```

But I will get ORA-02291 (integrity constraint violation) :-(

Comment: if you use a transaction you still need to insert in the correct order

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make the constraint deferrable , this way it is not checked until the commit. There is a good article about it [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/ConstraintCheckingUpdates.php)

```
> drop table c
table C dropped.
> drop table p
table P dropped.
> create table p (id number primary key)
table P created.
> create table c (id number primary key, p_id number)
table C created.
> alter table c add constraint pk_p foreign key (p_id) references p (id) deferrable
table C altered.
> insert into c values ( 1, 1 )
1 rows inserted.
> insert into p values ( 1 )
1 rows inserted.
> commit
commited.
```

Comment: I too face this issue while deleting through addbatch(). DELETE sql for child record is added first then added DELETE sql for parent record. This is causing <ORA-02292: integrity constrain  violated - child record found> How to resolve this issue without CONSTRAINTS = DEFER ? Why this Addbatch is not excuting in the same order of sql added into it? please help.

Answer (score -2):

Transaction won't help you with that problem. You could try to disable the necessary constraints, insert your data and then enable the constraints again.

Comment: I'd really not recommend disabling DB constraints to then insert data. After all the DB constraints are there exactly to ensure data integrity. Disabling them would be very dangerous. What if the data is bad and they don't enable again? Making them deferrable would (IMHO) be a better solution.